# ISO C++ draft - 3.4.2/3 - Argument Dependant Name Lookup

Tags: c++, c++11, name-lookup

A point from the ISO C++ draft (n3290):

> **3.4.2/3 Argument Dependant Name Lookup:**
>
> Let `X` be the lookup set produced by unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1) and
>   let `Y` be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup
>   (deﬁned as follows). If `X` contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member (#1) or
> - a block-scope function
>     declaration that is not a using-declaration (#2) or
> - a declaration
>     that is neither a function or a function template (#3)
>
> then `Y` is empty. Otherwise `Y` is the set of declarations found in
>   the namespaces associated with the argument types as described below.
>   The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union
>   of `X` and `Y`.

Is there an example code snippet that demonstrates ADL involving #1, #2 and #3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code covers all the cases (also available at http://ideone.com/CbyJv). If you don't select C++0x in ideone, then case #2 is allowed (but gcc 4.5.2 catches it).

```
#include <iostream>

// ::f
void f (int i) { std::cout << "::f\n" ; }

// Simple case
void OK1() {
  f (99) ; // Calls ::f
}

// Argument-dependend lookup
namespace MyNamespace {
struct S { int i ; } ;
void f (S& s) { std::cout << "MyNamespace::f\n" ; }
}

void OK2() {
  MyNamespace::S s ;
  f (99) ;   // Calls ::f
  f (s) ;    // Calls MyNamespace::f because the type of s is declared in MyNamespace
}

// Declaration of a class member (#1)
struct C {
  static void ERROR1() {
    MyNamespace::S s ;
    f (s) ;        // Error: MyNamespace::f not matched, because Y is empty (#1)
  }
  static void f() { // Declaration of a class member (#1)
    std::cout << "C::f\n" ;
  }
} ;

// Block-scope function declaration (#2)
void ERROR2() {
  void f() ; // Block-scope function declaration (#2)
  MyNamespace::S s ;
  f (s) ;    // Error: MyNamespace::f not matched, because Y is empty (#2)
}

// Declaration that is neither a function or a function template (#3)
void ERROR3() {
  MyNamespace::S s ;
  f (s) ;            // OK: MyNamespace::f called
  typedef int f[3] ; // Declaration that is neither a function or a function template (#3)
  f (s) ;            // Error: MyNamespace::f not matched, because Y is empty (#3). This is an initialiser
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is pretty simple - if you look for a name N inside a class, and the class has a member N, that's it! You don't have to go looking anywhere else.

Number 2 I believe is similar, but inside a block

```
{
    void f(double);

    f(42);
}
```

the code will try to call the function f declared there, if possible, and give up otherwise.

Number 3 is again similar. If you look for the name N and find something with that name that is not a function, you don't have to go looking for overloads.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is also called a Koenig Lookup. I don't have examples for all 3 to hand, but Bo Persson has already provided some.